# Runtime Error in Minion Game problem (HackerRank)

Tags: python

Below is my function to solve the **Minion Game problem** on [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-minion-game/problem) along with the problem description.

**It works wonderfully with regular-length strings, like 'banana'**, but when it comes to really long ones (ones that produce output counter in the vicinity of *7501500*, result in a runtime error (or memory error, depending on where you run it).

There must be a way to optimize the code. Can anybody advise?

```
"""Kevin and Stuart want to play the 'The Minion Game'.

Game Rules

Both players are given the same string, S.
Both players have to make substrings using the letters of the string S.

Stuart has to make words starting with consonants.
Kevin has to make words starting with vowels.
The game ends when both players have made all possible substrings.

Scoring
A player gets +1 point for each occurrence of the substring in the string S.

For Example:
String
S = BANANA
Kevin's vowel beginning word = ANA
Here, ANA occurs twice in BANANA. Hence, Kevin will get 2 Points. 
"""

def minions(s):
    vowels = ['A','E','I','O','U']
    s = s.upper()
    n = len(s)

    kevin = dict()
    stuart = dict()

    # list all string variations using list comprehension
    lst = [s[i:j+1] for i in range(n) for j in range(i,n)]

    # populate dictionaries
    for i in lst:
        if i[0] in vowels:
            if i in kevin:
                kevin[i] += 1
            else:   
                kevin[i] = 1
        else:
            if i in stuart:
                stuart[i] += 1
            else:
                stuart[i] = 1

    kevin_sm = 0    
    for x,y in kevin.items():
        kevin_sm += y

    stuart_sm = 0    
    for x,y in stuart.items():
        stuart_sm += y

    if kevin_sm > stuart_sm:
        print("Kevin {}".format(kevin_sm))
    elif kevin_sm == stuart_sm:
        print("Draw")
    else:
        print("Stuart {}".format(stuart_sm))
```

Example of a problematic string:

```
NANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANAN
```

Comment: For which exact example strings does the code run out of support? Are you sure your code is ready for review if the code doesn't complete all testcases? Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: added an example string to the problem body. The code doesn't complete all testcases precisely because of the problem I mentioned.

Comment: Code Review is a community where programmers peer-review your working code to address issues such as security, maintainability, performance, and scalability. We require that the code be working correctly, to the best of the author's knowledge, before proceeding with a review. Feel free to come back once the code passes the testcases.

Comment: The question very much is about performance and scalability. Their code *works* but is not performant enough and does not scale well. They could have just not mentioned that a test case (one that is about performance/scalability, not core functionality) is failing and the question would have been on topic, just by virtue of them asking "Can this be made more performant?". The code even **works for the provided test case** that OP said failed (on the HackerRank website); it just happens to take 2 minutes (recent i7) and 8GBs of RAM...

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Noted for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By storing all possible substrings in a dictionary, you require memory for all the duplicates your are creating.
This is probably the cause for the memory errors.

You also iterate over two dictionaries and the (long) list, which will be slower than what is described below.
Creating the `lst` in the first place requires two nested `for` loops; they don't have quadratic complexity, but are expensive still.

---

The problem can be tackled very differently if seen like in the following.
Take the example of `BANANA`.
Its length is `word_length = 6`.
You look at the first letter, `B`; it's a consonant.
As such, Stuart would score for this one.

Of course, the substring `BANANA` occurs only once in `BANANA`.
However, you can count all truncations of it as their own substrings.
One by one, you chop off the last letter, leading you to:

```
BANANA
BANAN
BANA
BAN
BA
B
```

All of these are substrings found in `BANANA`.
Remember, we are still looking at the first letter, `B`, which is indexed as `0`.
We found `word_length - i = 6 - 0 = 6` valid substrings, all of which count towards Stuart's score.

Let's see if the above pattern holds going forward.
The next letter is `A`, `i` becomes `1`.
`word_length` is a constant.

```
ANANA
ANAN
ANA
AN
A
```

This makes for `6 - 1 = 5` valid substrings, counted towards Kevin's score this time.

The third step looks like:

```
NANA
NAN
NA
N
```

with a score of `word_length - i = 6 - 2 = 4` for Stuart.

Note that substrings which occur more than once are counted correctly.
For example, the substring `NA` will be counted twice in the overall score.
Until now, it has been accounted for once, in the third step.
The next time it is counted will be in the fifth step, where the substrings looks like:

```
NA
N
```

As such, `N` will also be counted correctly (twice).

---

Let the input string length be \$ n \$.
In this case, the below approach only iterates over it once, leading to \$ \mathcal{O}(n) \$, linear, complexity.
The rest is just incrementing integers, which is very cheap.
`word_length` has to be computed once, which is \$ \mathcal{O}(1) \$ (constant/cheap).

```py
def minion_game(word):
    # word = input()

    vowels = "AEIOU"

    vowel_score = 0
    consonant_score = 0

    word_length = len(word)
    for idx, letter in enumerate(word):
        delta = word_length - idx
        if letter in vowels:
            vowel_score += delta
        else:
            consonant_score += delta

    if vowel_score > consonant_score:
        print("Kevin", vowel_score)
    elif vowel_score < consonant_score:
        print("Stuart", consonant_score)
    else:
        print("Draw")
```

---

Other points on your code:

```py
 for x,y in kevin.items():
        kevin_sm += y
```

can just be

```py
 for y in kevin.values():
        kevin_sm += y
```

---

```py
vowels = ['A','E','I','O','U']
```

can, in this context, just be

```py
vowels = "AEIOU"
```

It will behave the same for the `in` lookup.
You will want a list if you required a mutable object.

---

```py
for i in lst:
```

is very misleading variable naming.
`lst` is a list of string slices, and not indices (`i`).
It should read something like

```py
for substring in substrings:
```

(aka, also rename the too-generic `lst` variable).

Comment: `vowels = "AEIOU"` is really neat. you could omit the delta calculation altogether if you were to e.g. `enumerate( reversed( word ), 1 )` or `zip( word, range( word_length, 0, -1 ) )` switching indices.

Comment: Good point. Usually I'm not a fan of densifying code too much, but this is useful and readable.

Comment: @ALexPovel, thank you very much for your elaborate answer. This really helps a lot.